# Is there a simple way to concatenate columns in pandas from another data frame?

Tags: python, pandas, concatenation

Hey I am looking for a smart and simple way to concatenate 2 columns in pandas from another data frame into a new one. My old data frame looks like:

| name1 | name2 | name3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| tom | alice | bob |
| tom | lisa | max |
| alice | laura | bob |

The new data frame has only 2 columns (A,B). I want to compare every column form the old data frame in the new one like: name1 & name2, after that name1 & name3 and at least name2 & name3

Answer (score 0):

I found a good and easy way. this one works:

```
import pandas as pd 
from itertools import combinations

df = pd.read_csv('namen.csv', sep=";")

arr = ['name1','name2','name3']
r = 2 
combs = [x for x in combinations(arr, 2) ] 

df_new = pd.DataFrame(columns=['A', 'B']) 

for i in range(0,len(combs)-1):
    df_temp = df[[combs[i][0],combs[i][1]]].copy()
    df_temp.columns = df_new.columns
    df_new = pd.concat([df_kanten, df_new],ignore_index=True)
```

`